# jsconfig.json gives ts errors

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, nuxt.js, vscode-jsconfig

I am having `jsconfig.json` in my root directory using `Nuxt.js` project.
And I am having an error:

```
File '/home/mike/Documents/nuxt/node_modules/dotenv/types' not found.
  The file is in the program because:
    Root file specified for compilation
```

Actually 5 errors in a first line of `jsconfig.json`:
[image: Errors]

I don't even use `typescript` and I didn't set any `typescript` options while creating `Nuxt.js project`

`jsconfig.json` content:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["./*"],
      "@/*": ["./*"],
      "~~/*": ["./*"],
      "@@/*": ["./*"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", ".nuxt", "dist"]
}
```

I don't understand where they come from.
How do I get rid of this errors?
There's no option `quick fix` so I can't `ignore errors for entire file`

Answer (score 25):

After trying several solutions, I have just added `"exclude": ["node_modules"]` and restarted VScode. The error went away.

Comment: Have you tried putting it on `jsconfig.json` ?

Comment: I honestly don’t remember what did I do, but the error is gone.

Comment: Seem to be working after adding it to jsconfig.json.

Answer (score 15):

Just reload VSCode by typing `ctrl + shift + p` then type `reload window` and it should work.

Answer (score 10):

I ran into this and just exiting and relaunching VSCode (from the icon) seemed to fix it.

I'd originally started via `code .` so I'm thinking perhaps the instance with the error had picked up a weird env var from my terminal.

Answer (score 5):

In my case the problem was that the project is in a subfolder inside monorepo.

So the solution was changing it into add `./` before `node_modules`:

```
"exclude": ["./node_modules", ".nuxt", "dist"],
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to install and rebuild project, Hope this will help,

```
 npm install --save @types/dotenv
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I just initialized github repo and the problem disappeared. If the problem will appear again I'll try your solution.

Comment: I sorta figured it out, the error message appears on a fresh start (when I run my PC and open VSCode) and the error message disappears once I commit changes to my GitHub repo. Do you have any idea why would it be like that?

Comment: Strange behavior, not sure why this, but I will suggest install 'types' as suggested above or delete node_modules and package-lock.json and install fresh npm.

Comment: adding the types manually gives warning `npm WARN deprecated @types/dotenv@8.2.0: This is a stub types definition. dotenv provides its own type definitions, so you do not need this installed.`

Answer (score 0):

This error usually comes from different @types (typescript) folders with conflicting versions try to delete the folder from folder & see what happens.