# VS2022 VueJs Standalone Template TS Errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, vue.js, visual-studio-2022

The new Standalone project templates for Asp.Net CORE 6 integration with TS/JS Angular, React, and VueJs in VS2022 look like a streamlined way to combine any of these technologies with a .Net Asp.Net API back-end in a single solution.

I successfully implemented the steps in the VueJs Javascript version at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-asp-net-core-with-vue?view=vs-2022 using the Javascript Vue Standalone template.  Everything is running correctly with the VueJs successfully pulling data from the back-end Asp.Net Core 6 project.

One issue that still seems to be a problem is that default installation leaves you with 20+ Typescript errors in the VS Error List after installation is complete. They don't seem to be affecting compilation but it leaves the process unfinished and clunky.

The bug has been reported through Microsoft Visual Studio Feedback. Here is the issue: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/vue-typescript-template-in-2022-preview-3-reports-1/1507435  Please up-vote it if you feel it is useful.

I am not that familiar with d.ts entries, are there any workarounds to fix these errors?

[image: Visual Studio 2022 Standalone Typescript Errors]

Comment: Please include errors as text, not as an image of errors. Search engines will not find the errors without the text.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68879795/vscode-jsconfig-json-gives-ts-errors-root-file-specified-for-compilation

Comment: Estus Flask - This question may have a similar underlying cause but is about Visual Studio 2022, not about Visual Studio Code. There is no jsconfig.json in the project. Perhaps one of the other configs present could - "exclude": ["node_modules"] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 4/5/2022, it looks like this is now "Fixed - Pending Release" according to the linked Developer Community topic at:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/vue-typescript-template-in-2022-preview-3-reports-1/1507435

If I find out any additional release details I will post here.