# Jest: Typescript TS6059 rootDir warning on FeathersJS tests

Tags: typescript, jestjs, feathersjs, ts-jest

I have a Typescript setup of FeathersJS with tests based on the feathers generated services.

Randomly, but especially after a fresh setup, I have this warning occurrence:

```
ts-jest[ts-compiler] (WARN) error TS6059: File '/api/test/services/users.test.ts' is not under 'rootDir' '/api/src'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.
  The file is in the program because:
    Root file specified for compilation
```

Note: This warning appears multiple times for many test of many services.

How to resolve this warning properly?

I have not so much more information to give right now. Don't hesitate to ask for specific config or example, I'll update the thread accordingly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jsconfig.json gives ts errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66868663/jsconfig-json-gives-ts-errors)